# Display Larger version of image when image clicked

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how to achieve this as I want something very lean and don't want to use light box. Here is my code so far. It automatically adds a click event to each image and calls a function to display the path of where the large image is. Now I just need to display the large image like a modal window in the center of the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#imageContainer img').each(function (index) {
                if ($(this).attr('onclick') != null) {                    
                    if ($(this).attr('onclick').indexOf("runThis()") == -1) {                        
                        $(this).click(function () {
                            $(this).attr('onclick');
                            var src = $(this).attr("src");
                            ShowLargeImage(src);
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {                    
                    $(this).click(function () {                        
                        var src = $(this).attr("src");
                        ShowLargeImage(src);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        function ShowLargeImage(imagePath) {
            alert(imagePath.replace("small","large"));
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="imageContainer">        
        <br />
        <br />        
        <img src="/img/small/image3.jpg" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <img src="/img/small/image2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <img src="/img/small/image3.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...come to think of it, I am open to using a plugin but would like something that will allow me to pass in the image path, and also something that doesn't require anchor tags around the image

Comment: You don't need to give up lightbox or other such plugins for that. Just write your own code that does what you want and  after that load in the lightbox plugin and thadaa. For example, if you want to make it easier for yourself, you could generate the `link` element around the `img` and copy the path from the image while changing the `small` to `large`. Of you might want to keep in mind that it is not necessarily the best option because there wouldn't be link to the bigger image if js was disabled by some reason, if that is something you want to take into consideration.

Comment: For example http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/pkSxc/

Comment: Joonas, thanks for the input. I was considering this but I've only used lightbox once and I noticed that it wanted everything wrapped in list items contained in an unordered list. If I can find a lightbox that doesn't require the <ul><li></li></ul> type structure I'd be set!

Comment: Here's the same thing with lightbox 2 http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/pkSxc/2/ ( Note that none of the lightbox images are linked, so it looks a bit weird. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zrhhx/1/)

```
$('#imageContainer img').each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).attr('onclick') != null) {                    
        if ($(this).attr('onclick').indexOf("runThis()") == -1) {                        
            $(this).click(function () {
                $(this).attr('onclick');
                var src = $(this).attr("src");
                ShowLargeImage(src);
            });
        }
    }
    else {                    
        $(this).click(function () {                        
            var src = $(this).attr("src");
            ShowLargeImage(src);
        });
    }
});

$('body').on('click', '.modal-overlay', function () {
    $('.modal-overlay, .modal-img').remove();
});

function ShowLargeImage(imagePath) {
    $('body').append('<div class="modal-overlay"></div><div class="modal-img"><img src="' + imagePath.replace("small","large") + '" /></div>');
}
​
```

You can modify the css to get the image properly aligned, add a close button etc.. but the basic idea is there ;)

**Edit:**

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/Zrhhx/5/) with the image centered and an extra fading effect giving it a little more shablam!

Comment: IE acts a little crazy with everything you mean? :) No serious, IE9 works fine for me, IE7 and IE8 doesn't support opacity so the overlay is black. That's about it for me :)